# IllegalState when creating interface with Android 4.0's VpnService.Builder

Tags: android, networking, network-programming

I am experimenting with the VpnService that was added to Android in SDK 4.0. I have gotten as far as starting the VpnService, however, I am unable to create the virtual interface. My code throws an IllegalStateException and I am not able to figure out why. The code is inside a Thread, which is an inner-class of my VPNService-class.

My cut down example looks like this:

```
        ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = null;

        VpnService.Builder b = new VpnService.Builder();
        try{
            b.addAddress("10.0.6.2", 24);
            b.setMtu(1460);
            b.setSession("TunnelTest");
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
            Log.v("Service", "Address is invalid!");
            stopSelf();
            return;
        }

        try{
            pfd = b.establish();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
            Log.v("Service", "Interface was provided with an illegal argument");
        } catch (IllegalStateException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v("Service", "Illegal state");
        } catch (SecurityException e){
            Log.v("Service", "Security exception thrown");
```

What I try to do here is to create a virtual interface with IP 10.0.6.2, belonging to the 10.6.0.0/24 subnet. The exception is thrown by the b.establish() call.

This is the full stack trace:

```
11-30 17:51:10.863: W/System.err(2741): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create interface
11-30 17:51:10.875: W/System.err(2741):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1335)
11-30 17:51:10.875: W/System.err(2741):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
11-30 17:51:10.875: W/System.err(2741):     at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.establishVpn(IConnectivityManager.java:1321)
11-30 17:51:10.875: W/System.err(2741):     at android.net.VpnService$Builder.establish(VpnService.java:472)
11-30 17:51:10.875: W/System.err(2741):     at no.simtel.TestVpnService$TestVpn.run(TestVpnService.java:37)
```

Comment: Are you developing on the emulator? What else is in the logcat output?

Comment: Yes, logcat turned out to provide the solution. It seems like there is something wrong in my ICS build, because tun.ko is not inserted automatically. However, if I do insmod myself and then run my application, it works fine.

Comment: In that case, I'll create an answer. ;-)

Comment: I'm getting the same error on Kindle Fire with Cyanogen, but not every time. Any other explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `adb logcat` to verify that you are running into [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21030).

Comment: I can add that after some extensive debugging and reading, it is most likely caused by a bug in your ICS-version. When I do insmod manually, all is well with the code above.